# redux reducer not re-rendering components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Context: I am trying to make a web client that uses react redux and socket.io. The design is inspired by whatsapp and is honestly just a fun little side project I am using to learn react and redux.

The main issue is I have a ActiveChat component that does not re-render upon the store changing and recognizing the change . Redux Devtools even shows the diff and change in state.

The component has been connected:

```
//Redux Mapping for Store and Actions
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { activeChat: state.activeChat };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    updateActiveChat: chat => dispatch(updateActiveChat(chat))
  }
}

const activeChatConnected = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ActiveChat)


export default activeChatConnected;
```

I had the idea that I may somehow not be keeping the state pure as this is my first tango with state immutability in javascript and was hoping i'd receive help for the commmunity

The code is available here : https://github.com/YourFavouriteOreo/ChatClient ( Feedback is ALWAYS welcome as I am trying to get better at javascript )

The code snippet in question specifically is :

```
# src/reducers
const rootReducer = (state = initialState,action) => {
      switch(action.type){
          case SELECT_ACTIVE:
          // Select Active Chat so as to display chat content
            var newActive = Object.assign(state.chats[action.payload.index])
            newActive["index"]= action.payload.index
            return {...state,activeChat:newActive}
          case UPDATE_CHAT:
          // Update store with new Chat Content
            var chats = Object.assign(state.chats)
            chats[state.activeChat.index].chatLogs.concat(action.payload)
            return {...state,chats}
          default:
          return state
      }
}
```

I have currently hotfixed this by setting state right after the action but this is not ideal as once I'll be using sockets , setState being async could lead to certain issues.

```
inputHandler = logs => {
    // Handle Input from chatInput
    var newState = this.state.chatLogs;
    newState.push(logs);
    //Redux Action
    this.props.updateActiveChat(logs)
    console.log(this.state.chatLogs);
    // BAD HOTFIX
    this.setState({});
};
```

Edit: This was asked so I will add it here . The `return {...state,chats}` does in-fact get result into return `{...state, chats:chats}`

EDIT2:

```
// actions
import {SELECT_ACTIVE, UPDATE_CHAT} from "../constants/action-types"

export const selectActiveChat = selected => ({type: SELECT_ACTIVE, payload:selected})
export const updateActiveChat = chat => ({type: UPDATE_CHAT, payload:chat})
```

EDIT 3 :

// render function for activeChat component

```
render() {
    if (this.state != null){
      return (
        <div className="column is-8 customColumn-right">
          <div className="topColumn">
            <h1 style={{fontFamily:"Quicksand,sans-serif", fontWeight:"bold", fontSize:"1.1rem"}}> {this.state.chatName} </h1>
            <p style={{fontFamily:"Roboto,sans-serif",marginLeft: "0.75rem",lineHeight:"1"}}> Chat Participants </p>
          </div>
          <ChatContent
            chatLogs={this.props.activeChat.chatLogs}
            isTyping={this.state.isTyping}
          />
          <ChatInput postSubmit={this.inputHandler} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    else {
      return <NoActiveChat/>
    }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
// Change Props on Receive 
console.log("das new props");
this.setState({
  chatName: newProps.activeChat.chatName,
  chatLogs: newProps.activeChat.chatLogs,
  isTyping: newProps.activeChat.isTyping
})
}
```

Comment: Please show the `updateActiveChat()` action creator.

Comment: And show the `render()` (or maybe a simplified version) from your component. Also provide evidence that your component is not rendered as you expect.

Comment: I have added all the git code in the project information . 

Action is available here : https://github.com/YourFavouriteOreo/ChatClient/blob/master/frontend/src/actions/index.js

ActiveChat Component here: 
https://github.com/YourFavouriteOreo/ChatClient/blob/master/frontend/src/components/activeChat.js

Comment: The links are great, but in case they ever become invalid, it helps to show your complete code here. (Note: "Complete" means enough to reproduce the behavior you are asking about. "Complete" does NOT mean all of the code in your app.)

Comment: In this particular case, it will also help to see your render() method in your question here as well as any other parts of your component class that are relevant.

Comment: Added :D . Basically the whole component is here xD .

Comment: Great. I am taking a look now. On a side note, it seems to me that you don't need `componentWillReceiveProps()`. If you remove this function, you can use properties of `this.props.activeChat` instead of `this.state` in your render method, for example `this.props.activeChat.isTyping` instead of `this.state.isTyping`.

Comment: I don't see anything that is obviously wrong here. I assume that `ChatInput` renders something like a `<input type=text>` and maybe a button and when the user presses enter or clicks the button, then it calls `postSubmit()`. This should then dispatch the action which eventually gets passed into the reducer. I suggest that you add some `console.log()` calls to the reducer to check if it is called. Put one above the `switch` and another in the `case`. Be sure to log the value of `chats`, too.

Comment: I have logged the values in every step cause I thought I might be missing data somewhere . However I am not . The reducer get's called and the redux store registers the change  and you are correct chat input is just an input box with it's own state . The main issue is activeChat does not register the change in props until setState is called . Willreceiveprops doesn't detect it as well.

Comment: what about ChatContent? Have you logged its props during its render() method?

Comment: ChatContent will only change once the props from ActiveChat change since it's being passed props . ChatContent does not re-render because ActiveChat does not re-render . This project is current hosted on [link](http://oreoclient.herokuapp.com) with the hotfix included. However just imagine the new input u enter is not updating the state .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by executing concat differently in the reducer. I don't understand how this changed the end result since the object still changes but this seemed to fix .

Instead of :

```
      case UPDATE_CHAT:
      // Update store with new Chat Content
        console.log("Update chat action executed");
        var chatState = Object.assign({},state)
        chatState.chats[state.activeChat.index].chatLogs.concat(action.payload)
        return {...chatState}
```

I did:

```
          case UPDATE_CHAT:
          // Update store with new Chat Content
            console.log("Update chat action executed");
            var chatState = Object.assign({},state)
            chatState.chats[state.activeChat.index].chatLogs = chatState.chats[state.activeChat.index].chatLogs.concat(action.payload)
            return {...chatState}
```

EDIT: It turns out that Object.assign() does a shallow clone, this means that nested objects are references rather than copies . If you want to do a deepClone . You can use cloneDeep from lodash, I realized this with other problems I ended up getting later with other functions .

The new case handler is as follows in my solution.

**_ is my import for lodash**

```
          case UPDATE_CHAT:
      // Update store with new Chat Content
      console.log("Update chat action executed");
        var chatState = _.cloneDeep(state)
        chatState.chats[state.activeChat.index].chatLogs = chatState.chats[state.activeChat.index].chatLogs.concat(action.payload)
        return {...chatState}
```